# Faster way to run animated weather radar

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, bing-maps

I'm attempting to run an animated radar animation using a tile server and a map control. The code works, but it's extremely slow.

The code (When user plays the animation)

```
map.TileSources.Clear();
map.TileSources.Add(new TileSource("example.html/45minutesold");
map.TileSources.Clear();
map.TileSources.Add(new TileSource("example.html/40minutesold");
map.TileSources.Clear();
map.TileSources.Add(new TileSource("example.html/35minutesold");
```

... This goes on and on until it gets to the current time, then I run the method again and repeat until the user pauses.
 This works perfectly fine, with the problem being that the map.TileSources.Clear() method is EXTREMELY slow and inefficent, and to top it off, the TileSources.Add method isn't much faster.

Any ideas on how to make this fast enough to actually work? I thought about stitching these images together into an animated GIF then adding that as a tilesource, but I have no idea how to do that. Another option I considered was somehow preloading this data.

My tile source:
http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/ogc/
Example of use:

```
blizzardmap.TileSources.Add(new TileSource("http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m05m/{zoomLevel}/{x}/{y}.png?" + DateTime.Now.ToString()));
```

Comment: Another quick solution that I'm thinking about, would be to dynamically compose the overlay on the whole control and generate the information on a single image that would be simpler (and quicker) to modify. It's not supported in the native control but you can retrieve the bounding box and generate the appropriate overlay.

Answer (score 1):

One of our MVP's did a lot of analysis around this a while back using our JavaScript map control. He wrote a 5 part series on this. These might give you some ideas of things to try.

https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/the-4th-dimension-creating-dynamic-animated-tile-layers-in-bing-maps-ajax-v7-part-1/

https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/the-4th-dimension-creating-dynamic-animated-tile-layers-in-bing-maps-ajax-v7-part-2/

https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/the-4th-dimension-creating-dynamic-animated-tile-layers-in-bing-maps-ajax-v7-part-3-revised/

https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/the-4th-dimension-creating-dynamic-animated-tile-layers-in-bing-maps-ajax-v7-part-4/

https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/the-4th-dimension-creating-dynamic-animated-tile-layers-in-bing-maps-ajax-v7-part-5/

That said, I can see this being difficult to achieve on WP. The loading of the tiles will be slower on a mobile device than in a web browser.